# Elsa workflow designer drag and drop not work

Tags: drag-and-drop, elsa-workflows

I have a problem with the drag & drop when I use the designer.
I tried to add a "Fork-Join" but I can't connect the Branches with the Join.
When I try to drag them, it moves the whole workflow.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If the provided answer helped you, please accept it to acknowledge the effort he/she made to help you out

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://elsa-workflows.github.io/elsa-core/docs/next/designer/designer-using-the-designer#connecting-to-existing-activities):

To connect an outcome to an existing activity:

1. Press and hold the SHIFT button while left-clicking the outcome from which you wish to connect.
2. Left-click on the target activity (no need to keep pressing SHIFT)

If that doesn't work, then it must be a bug. In which case I would encourage you to [file a bug](https://github.com/elsa-workflows/elsa-core/issues/new).